# Size of derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, turbo-c++

```
class mango
{
    int yellow;
    char leaf[30];
};

class strawberry : public mango 
{
      public:
      int lol;
};
```

Why is it necessary to add the size of yellow and leaf to find the total size of strawberry even-though they are not inherited?

Comment: In what way are `yellow` and `leaf` not inherited, in your opinion?  There's a difference between whether the member is inherited and whether the child can access the inherited member.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein As they are private data members.

Comment: But since in your code, a strawberry is a mango, it still has everything a mango has.

Comment: But, it is taught in my school that only non-private members are inherited. Also, what is the use of inheriting yellow and leaf if Strawberry cannot use them.

Comment: If I hand you a suitcase with a mango locked inside, you still have to carry the mango around even though you can't access it.

Comment: *It is taught in my school that only non-private members are inherited*. It is also taught in your school that Turbo C++ is a C++ compiler. Perhaps your teacher is no good, or perhaps you just mis-understood. Please go back to your notes and your text book where all this will be explained.

Comment: _'non-private members are inherited'_ I'd say the **full** sentence goes: "only non-private members are inherited **to be accessible**"

Comment: @Casey That was a good analogy sir.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Probably I mis-understood because it's pretty difficult for me to study CS.I always mess up these little concepts.

Comment: The question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it necessary to add the size of yellow and leaf to find the
>   total size of strawberry even-though they are not inherited?

They **are** inherited, and I can prove it:

```
class mango
{
    int yellow;
    char leaf[30];
public:
    int getYellow() { return yellow; }
    mango() : yellow(42) {}
};

class strawberry : public mango 
{
      public:
      int lol;
  public:
  int doIt() { return getYellow(); }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  strawberry s;
  std::cout << s.doIt();
};
```

Output is:

```
42
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course they're inherited. They're not *visible* to the `strawberry`, but they're still a part of the `mango` from which it inherits.

A `strawberry` could use public or protected methods of a `mango` which in turn used those members.

Comment: But, it is taught in my school that only non-private members are inherited. Also, what is the use of inheriting yellow and leaf if Strawberry cannot use them?

Comment: Actually, they are visible.  You're just not allowed to use them, but they are still found by name lookup.

Comment: A `strawberry` could use them by calling public or protected methods  of a `mango` which used those private members.

Comment: @Rajath Well you were taught wrong in your school. Only non-private members are *accessible*, private members are *visible* in derived classes but not accessible. Even if `strawberry` cannot access those members, they're presumably needed by `mango` to function properly.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't understand that distinction. Do you have a compilable code snippet to explain?

Comment: @Roddy The distinction is that if you were access `yellow` within `strawberry` the error message would say that that member is not accessible because it is private. If it were not visible the error message would be more along the lines of 'no member named `yellow` in `strawberry`'

Comment: @Roddy `int yellow;`, then in a member function of `strawberry`: `int strawberry::mf() { return yellow; }`.  You will get an error, because the private member is found by name lookup, and hides the global variable of the same name.